# Robocopy, large files slow down multiple thread copy

Tags: robocopy

For robocopy, can I have other unused threads move on to another file without waiting for the other threads to finish? I tend to notice that when I am copying files with one larger file, one thread takes longer, meaning that the other threads are not doing anything.

Comment: Robocopy already does this when you use the `/MT` switch. You need to provide more Information about what your problem is. Maybe you are misunderstanding what multi-threaded is? It means robocopy will download multiple files simultaneously and as each thread is freed up it will move on to the next file. It will NOT, however, use multiple threads to download the same file.

Comment: @Appleoddity When I display the files being transfer, everything above the file still being transferred seems to freeze.